# How to access a variable across all js files of an HTML go-gin

Tags: javascript, html, go, go-templates

I am using gin templating and to render an HTML I use

```
c.Writer.Header().Set("username", "myname")
c.HTML(200, "myservices", gin.H{
    "title":    "Dashboard",
    "username": "myname" })
```

I want to pass a variable (username) so that I can access that in the js files attached to my template. I can access the username variable in template using `{{.username}}`. How can make it global so that I can also access it across all the js files as well. I tried setting it in header but I can access that only when the HTML is loaded. I won't be able to use it before the template is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a Javascript code into the HTML page (e.g. in the `<head>` section) where you create Javascript variables, and initialize them with the parameters passed to the template execution.

See this example:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "title":    "Test page",
        "username": "bob",
        "counter":  12,
    }
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const templ = `<html><head>
<script>
    var _title = {{.title}};
    var _username = {{.username}};
    var _counter = {{.counter}};
</script>
</head><body>
</body>
</html>`
```

This results in an HTML document (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nKAgzpr-9u)):

```
<html><head>
<script>
    var _title = "Test page";
    var _username = "bob";
    var _counter =  12 ;
</script>
</head><body>
</body>
</html>
```

What this means is that other Javascript code in the page (either inlined or referenced, external) will see the variables `_title`, `_username`, `_counter` and use them as regular variables, and they are initialized with values we passed to [`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute).

Note that the [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package performs contextual escaping. See that it inserted the result of `{{.title}}` in quotes because it is a `string` and that is how it should be written in Javascript code, but no quotes were added when inserting the result of `{{.counter}}`, because it is a value of type `int`.

Also note that you should use a unique naming strategy to avoid collision with existing variables or variables that may be used in other Javascript code. Usually a special prefix (or postfix) does it.

Also check out this related question: [Referencing Go array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751637/referencing-go-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Do we really need to use Template.Execute(). Can't we pass the variables the way I did using c.HTML? I can still access those variables as `{{.username}}`. Can't I just store them as global variables like you did?

Comment: @love2code You don't need to use that, you can just pass them using `c.HTML()`. I used `Template.Execute()` so that it works on the Go Playground, because the `github.com/gin-gonic/gin` package cannot be imported there. The principle to create and initialize Javascript variables is what matters, there rest is just so that it can run on the Go Playground.